# Assign to an Dataframe column names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have an problem my CSV File has no column names. It starts with the data entries. So I was asking my self if there is an way to assign to an Dataframe column name. I need the column names to get specific columns for datascience.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

birthday = pd.read_csv("birthday.csv")

print(list(birthday.columns.values))
```

I hope there is an way without writing the file again because it does take some times. Around 1 hour.

Hopefully you can help me.

Best Regards
Tobias

Comment: short answer is, unless you're willing to overwrite a line of data, you cannot.

Comment: @TobiasDex I'm not sure but passing either `header` or `names` in `read_csv` should work.

Comment: @coldspeed No I dont want overwrite. I just wanna assign it. And then I can print out special columns

Comment: @krishna I try it out